Comapring 2 Hashsets results in data that is zero
I have hashset1 that has items as filenames from one file share and hashset2 that has items as filenames from another file share. I want to find all the file names that are common in both and put them in a third hashset viz $setDiff.There can't be no duplicates. The condition should work even if one of the set is empty, i think it would work if you do the diff is my expectation.
I find that its not working sometimes, and i get 0, although i see there are files that match in both sets.
I have a sample screenshot of the file names of the 2 sets that i am trying to compare.

$setOrig = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.String]
$setOrigNames = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.String]
$setArchived = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.String]
$setArchivedNames = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.String]'
$setDiff = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.String]
$origNamePathPair = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]'
$archNamePathPair = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]'
$setOrig = Get-ChildItem  -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Include("*.png")$setArchived | 
ForEach-Object { $archNamePathPair[$_.BaseName] = $setArchived[$i], $i++ }

$idx = 0
$setOrig | ForEach-Object { $origNamePathPair[$_.BaseName] = $setOrig[$idx], $idx++ 
 }
$setOrigNames = $setOrig | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName}       
$setArchivedNames = $setArchived | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName}
   
    $hash1 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
        [string[]] ($setOrigNames),
        [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCulture)

    $hash2 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
        [string[]] ($setArchivedNames),
        [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCulture)
    
    $setDiff = @(
    $hash2.Where{ $hashset1.Contains($_) }
    )

enter code here

your question lacks clarity

What is your code doing that you don’t expect? (Or what is it not doing that you do expect?). Your code is quite haphazard, btw - you’re piping $setArchived |  ForEach-Object { … } before you assign any data to $setArchived, and you initialise $hash1 but then never use it, and same for $origNamePathPair / $archNamePathPair. Maybe try to rationalise your code, and the answer may present itself…

"The condition should work even if one of the set is empty" - can you expand on this? How can something be in both, if one contains nothing?

I can see you’ve updated your code to $hash2.Where{ $hashset1.Contains($_) }, but $hashset1 isn’t defined anywhere - can you please test the code you’ve posted by cutting and pasting it from your post into a clean Powershell session and make sure it actually represents and reproduces your issue? If you can’t reproduce it just from the code you’ve posted then no-one else will be able to either…
